# PHP single loop through 2 MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, loops

Please review this code:

```
    $current_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `product_categories` WHERE `product`='{$_GET['id']}'");
    $all_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `categories`");
    $in = mysql_fetch_array($current_sql);

    while($ca = mysql_fetch_array($all_sql)){

        echo("<label><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"categories[]\" value=\"".$ca['ID']."\" class=\"cat_check\"");
        if($edit){
            if(in_array($ca['ID'], $in)){
                echo(" checked=\"checked\"");   
            }
        }
        echo("> " . $ca['category'] . "</label><br/>\n");

    }
```

This is the output:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="1" class="cat_check" checked="checked"> PS3 Games</label><br/> 
<label><input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="16" class="cat_check"> Category 2</label><br/> 
<label><input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="17" class="cat_check" checked="checked"> Category 3</label><br/> 
<label><input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="18" class="cat_check"> Category 4</label><br/> 
<label><input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="19" class="cat_check"> Category 5</label><br/>
```

The problem is only checkbox value="17" is supposed to be checked, there are 2 MySQL databases here are are the structures:

```
categories:

ID    |   name
1         PS3 Games
16        Category 3
17        Category 4
18        Category 5
19        Category 6

product_categories

category     |    product
1                 20
17                1
```

Please help!!

**UPDATE:**

Sorry forgot to add:

```
$_GET['id'] = 1
```

Comment: What is your the condition which will tell that this checkbox is to be checked.

Comment: Offtopic: you should either use prepared statements or use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) to escape `$_GET['id']` to avoid SQL injections.

Comment: can you do a var_dump($in);exit; right after $in = mysql_fetch_array($current_sql); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead

```
$in = mysql_fetch_array($current_sql);
```

do

```
while ($prod_cat = mysql_fetch_array($current_sql)) {
  $in[] = $prod_cat['cat_id']; // where cat_id is the category ID in product_categories table
}
```

Basically the problem is that [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) get you back 2 arrays and I guess that you have something like `array([0] = 1, [1] =17, etc ...)`. This is causing both categories to be checked. If you print_r the $in in your code, you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

This will only give you an array woth the first row in your mapping table, meaning it will contain 1 and 20 (category and product).

$in = mysql_fetch_array($current_sql);

You would want to iterate through it to get all categories in order to get the right functionality. BUT:

You'd be better off joining your product_categories into the same query, and keep some sort of boolean value to indicate which ones are already selected. The way you are doing it now won't work at all.

```
SELECT c.*, IFNULL(pc.category, 0, 1) as checked FROM `categories` c
LEFT JOIN `product_categories` pc ON pc.category = c.ID AND product = {$_GET['id']}
```

then you can check

```
if ($resultset['checked'])
```

Because it would be 1 if part of product_category, and 0 if not.

But be sure to escape your parameters or use prepared statements as somebody suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
   $current_sql = mysql_query("SELECT category FROM `product_categories` WHERE `product`='{$_GET['id']}' LIMIT 1");

if(($ca['ID']== $current_sql['ID'])){
                echo(" checked=\"checked\"");
            }

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$current_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `product_categories` WHERE `product`='{$_GET['id']}'");
$all_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `categories`");
$pcs = array();
    while($in=mysql_fetch_array($current_sql);)){
        $pcs[]=$in['ID']
    }

while($ca = mysql_fetch_array($all_sql)){

    echo("<label><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"categories[]\" value=\"".$ca['ID']."\" class=\"cat_check\"");
    if($edit){
        if(in_array($ca['ID'], $pcs)){
            echo(" checked=\"checked\"");   
        }
    }
    echo("> " . $ca['category'] . "</label><br/>\n");
}
```